# Installation Issue of CentOS 7

Tags: linux, partitioning, installation, multi-boot, centos-7

how i tried to install centOS 7 having centOS 6.4 already in the system and windows as well.
bootable DVD::::--> ISO is CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso....

and my problem is after manual partitioning option i found three different options 
1. New CentOS 7 Installation.
2.CentOS 6.4 for x86_64.
3.Unknown.
what exactly should i need to do in this stage so that i can have fresh CentOS 7 rather than already installed cenOS 6.4 and i do not want to lose windows partitions which are displayed in unknown options the third one...
what are the procedures now please suggest me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want option one,

As long as you haven't done anything with the windows partition during the manual partition step it should be fine and the centos install wont touch it.  but it will overwrite the old centos 6 install

but if you just want to upgrade from 6.4 - 7 this may be a better option for you

http://linuxsysconfig.com/2014/07/upgrade-to-centos-7/

it's the guide I used to do mine